# What are the criteria for choosing Turing award winners?

Tags: neural-networks

Why does not a researcher like Geoffrey Hinton with his valuable works in machine learning (especially neural networks) get Turing award?

Comment: [He won it for 2018 along with Yoshua Bengio and Yann LeCun](https://awards.acm.org/about/2018-turing) :)

Answer (score 1):

> [The ACM A.M. Turing Award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_Award) is an annual prize given by the Association
>   for Computing Machinery (ACM) to "an individual selected for
>   contributions of a technical nature made to the computing community".
>   It is stipulated that the contributions "should be of lasting and
>   major technical importance to the computer field". The Turing Award is
>   generally recognized as the highest distinction in computer science
>   and the "Nobel Prize of computing".